# Read File by ULONG at a time

Tags: c++, c, file, winapi

I am trying to adapt to some code which creates a char * to the head of some data. And then is able to increment that pointer unsigned long at a time to read the data.

I have been told a good way to do this is use ifstream to read the file (located somewhere on C:/) into a vector:

```
std::vector<int8_t>
```

But where my confusion is how do I then pull each piece of the file out in sizes of ULONG. I posted the logic below, this is communicating to hardware which needs data to be in that size, so they traverse the pointer at the sizeOf(ULONG) at a time until they read the end of the file(which they know by checking the file size). I know I need to somehow load this into memory.. but how do I traverse the same way

a small snippet of their code looks like this:

```
char* resData;
res = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(fpgaDevice), L"FPGADATA");
  resHandle = LoadResource(NULL, res);
  resData = (char*)LockResource(resHandle);
```

then to advance the file they advance the pointer by the size of the ULONG:

```
resData += sizeof(ULONG);
```

And to read the pointer simply use:

```
(ULONG*)resData
```

Comment: Are they using a memory-mapped file? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file

Comment: Never use both [tag:c++] and [tag:c] .....

Comment: `int8_t` probably isn't large enough since `ULONG` is probably `uint32_t`.

Comment: You've got a problem.  You tagged the C language, but the C language doesn't have `std::vector`.  I recommend you focus on one language before mixing or combing the two languages.  Also, update your language tags.

Comment: what's the point of reading data to a vector of int8_t and read uint32_t blocks of data by using a pointer to the vector buffer.... Why don't you just read the data to a vector of uint32_t and access the values by index ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your data is binary data in the correct native format (I think that's implied by your question).

So if your data is ULONGs don't use a char pointer use a ULONG pointer, like this

```
vector<int8_t> res;
// some code to read into res

// get the underlying data
ULONG* resData = (ULONG*)res.data();

// read a ULONG
ULONG someData = *resData;

// advance to the next ULONG
++resData;
```

The important part is the use of the `data()` method to access the vectors data.

Comment: this makes a lot more sense. I didn't realize you could cast a pointer like that from a  vector

Comment: Beware that four `int8_t` values may not satisfy alignment requirements to be accessed as a single `ULONG`. You will need to declare the pointer as unaligned to avoid crashes on alignment-sensitive CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

You have no reason to read into a vector. Your resource is already loaded into memory, so the conformant way is to `memcpy` the relevant parts directly into your variables. Here it could be:

```
...
char* resData = (char*)LockResource(resHandle);
...
ULONG myVar;
int offset = ...;    // the offset in the resource where your long value resides
memcpy(&myVar, resData+offset, sizeof(myVar));
```

That is all your ULONG variable can now be used...

---

If you no longer have a resource but a file you can use unformatted io methods over an `ifstream`:

```
std::ifstream in(file_name, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base_binary);
...
ULONG myVar;
int offset = ...;    // the offset in the resource where your long value resides
in.seekg(offset, std::ios_base::seekdir::beg);        // position the stream at the offset
in.read(static_cast<char *>(&myVar), sizeof(myVar));  // and read the bytes
```

Comment: well, that was the old code. All I have now is the path to my file.. so not sure if it is locked to memory now? Before they had the bin files loaded into the .exe itself

Comment: okay think i see what you mean. Although I don't think I'd have an offest because I would be right at the top of the file. I also am trying to use a pointer to do this where in this case I would have to keep recalled the read function?

Comment: You also need `SizeofResource(NULL, resHandle)` to find the data size